# C++ rule of 5 - segmentation fault on custom destructor

Tags: c++

I have been learning C++ for some time and started writing a larger project just to realise that whatever I was thinking about C++ is wrong.

Basically I have a class called `DenseVector` which holds doubles. I want to move, copy construct etc that vector to use it with vectors etc.

The class looks something like this:

---

DenseVector.h:

```
class DenseVector {
    
    private:
        double* values = nullptr;
        int size;
    public:
        DenseVector();
        DenseVector(int size);      
        DenseVector(double x, double y);       
        DenseVector(double x, double y, double z);       
        DenseVector(const DenseVector &other);
        DenseVector(DenseVector &&other);
        virtual ~DenseVector();

        DenseVector& operator=(const DenseVector& other);
        DenseVector& operator=(DenseVector&& other);
}
```

DenseVector.cpp

```
DenseVector::DenseVector() : DenseVector(3) {}

DenseVector::DenseVector(int size) : size(size) {
    this->values = new double[size + size % 2]{0};
}

DenseVector::DenseVector(double x, double y) {
    this->size = 2;
    this->values = new double[2]{x,y};
}

DenseVector::DenseVector(double x, double y, double z) {
    this->size = 3;
    this->values = new double[4]{x,y,z};
}

DenseVector::DenseVector(const DenseVector &other) : size(other.size) {
    this->values = new double[size + size % 2]{0};
    memcpy(values, other.values, size * sizeof(double));
}

DenseVector::DenseVector(DenseVector &&other) : values(other.values), size(other.size){}


DenseVector::~DenseVector() {
    if(values != nullptr){
        delete values;
        values = nullptr;
    }
}

DenseVector &DenseVector::operator=(const DenseVector &other) {
    this->size = other.size;
    memcpy(values, other.values, size * sizeof(double));
    return *this;
}

DenseVector &DenseVector::operator=(DenseVector &&other) {
    this->values = other.values;
    this->size = other.size;
    return *this;
}
```

I assume its a very straight forward implementation for mathematical vectors in C++. Note that size of the array internally is always a multiple of two. This is due to speedups using AVX/SSE which is not part of this question.

Basically I keep getting a Segmentation fault inside the deconstructor when trying to delete the value and I have no idea why this keeps on happening!

And example would be the following snippet:

```
   std::vector<DenseVector> positions;
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       positions.push_back({1,2,3});
   }
```

This really confuses me and I would be very very happy if someone could help me with this problem as this had happened to me before many times in other programs.
Also what would be the difference between using `push_back` and `emplace_back` in this case? Should one prefer one over the other one? I do not understand at which point objects will be created, moved, deleted etc.

Greetings
Finn

Comment: Your move constructor does (shallow) copy, not move.

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @FinnEggers, in a move copy, the pointers in the rvalue object are set to `nullptr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see at least two problems:

```
DenseVector &DenseVector::operator=(const DenseVector &other) {
    this->size = other.size;
    memcpy(values, other.values, size * sizeof(double));
    return *this;
}
```

You are not checking whether you have enough space in `this->values`. If `this->size` is smaller than `other->size`, you need to reallocate.

```
DenseVector::DenseVector(DenseVector &&other) : values(other.values),
                                                size(other.size){}

DenseVector &DenseVector::operator=(DenseVector &&other) {
    this->values = other.values;
    this->size = other.size;
    return *this;
}
```

In both cases you end up with two pointers pointing to the same memory. Now when you destroy both vectors, you get a double `delete`. You need to have `other->values = nullptr;` in both functions.

A better way to fix both issues it to use `std::vector` and rely on **the rule of zero**.

Comment: That sounds reasonable but I thought that when an object is moved, the old object will not be deleted?

Comment: @FinnEggers *the old object will not be deleted?* -- It has to be deleted at some point.  That's when you will run into the double-delete issue.

Comment: Mhm then what is the point of moving at all? I thought one would "simply" transfer the entire data of on object to the other

Comment: But your answer nails it. Thank you for your answer :) Now considering that delete will also be called on the moved object, this makes a lot of sense

Comment: @Finn an object itself is not moved anywhere. The heap resource is moved - taken over by the new object. Then you definitely want to `nullptr` the old object's resource pointer because its destructor must not delete the resource during imminent scope exit (or rejection as a temporary object). You no longer care about that old object but its pointer HAS TO BE invalidated in move ctor and move assignment.

Comment: Yeah I think I understand this now... C++ is so much more complicated than Java :D

Comment: Side note on shallow copies: Sometimes you may be interested in copying just the pointer, to share the data and avoid big copies. In this case make sure you use an std::shared_ptr the the data will be deleted when the last owner is destructed.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems.

The one in destructor is that `delete` should match with `new` not `new[]`.

You have to use `delete[]` here:

```
DenseVector::~DenseVector() {
    delete [] values;
}
```

Note: Deleting null pointer is fine, no test needed. setting values to `nullptr` is useless too, as reading the value after the object is destroyed is UB anyway.

Your move constructor doesn't move, but shallow copy, so you will have double delete, it should be

```
DenseVector::DenseVector(DenseVector &&other) /*noexcept*/: values(other.values), size(other.size)
{
    other.vlalues = nullptr;
    other.size = 0;
}
```

Comment: I have seen this before but I have seen many cases where people just use delete over delete[]. So I assume this is the way it should be done?

Comment: They invoke undefined behavior. (as with trivial destructor (as for double), most compilers do the same, the code seems to works).

Answer (score 0):

You have many problems:

first you should move objects in move-ctor and leave the moved-from in a valid state:

```
DenseVector::DenseVector(DenseVector &&other) : values(std::move(other.values)), size(std::move(other.size))
{
     other.values = nullptr;    
}
```

- You should use ctor-init list to initialize member data rather than assign to them inside ctor body after being default-init in ctor-init-list.

  ```
   DenseVector::DenseVector(int size) : size(size),
        values(new double[size]{0})
   {

   }
  ```

Also in the destructor you are freeing an array of doubles with `delete` which is Undefined Behavior so use it this way:

```
 delete[] values;
```

- You don't need to check in the dtor whether `values` is `nullptr` or not:

  ```
    delete[] values;
  ```

Comment: Is there an important difference between using the init-list and just using the body of the constructor?

Comment: Sure! using ctor body is just an assignment so the member data are written to twice: once default initialized int ctor-init-list (is allowed if and only if they are default-constructible). second in the assignment in the body of the constructor.